# Coinbase Pro API Invalid Signature ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coinbase-api

I'm trying to get simple account info from Coinbase Pro and can't seem to figure out the CB-ACCESS-SIGN header. I keep getting an "invalid signature" message.

**From Coinbase Pro API Docs:**

> The CB-ACCESS-SIGN header is generated by creating a sha256 HMAC using
> the base64-decoded secret key on the prehash string timestamp + method
>
> - requestPath + body (where + represents string concatenation) and base64-encode the output. The timestamp value is the same as the
>   CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP header.
>
> The body is the request body string or omitted if there is no request
> body (typically for GET requests).
>
> The method should be UPPER CASE.

**My Code:**

```
    <cfscript>
        
        accessKey = 'xxx';
        
        passPhrase = 'yyy';
        
        theSecret = 'zzz';
        
        // create an epoch time stamp
        theTime = now();
        utcTime = dateConvert('local2UTC',theTime);
        ISOtimeStamp = dateFormat(utcTime,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"T"&timeFormat(utcTime,"HH:mm:ss")&".761Z";
        timeStamp = numberFormat(dateDiff("s","January 1 1970 00:00",ISOtimeStamp) + 28800.761,"_.000");
        
        requestPath = '/accounts';
        
        theBody = "";
        
        method = "GET";
    
    
        // create the prehash string by concatenating required parts
        what = '#timeStamp#' & '#method#' & '#requestPath#' & '#theBody#';
        
        // decode the base64 secret
        theKey = binaryDecode(theSecret,"base64");
        
        // create s sha256 hmac with the key
        theHmac = hmac("#what#","#theKey#", "HMACSHA256");
        
        // encode the result
        cas = toBase64(theHmac);
        
        
    </cfscript>
        
    <cfhttp url="https://api.pro.coinbase.com/v2/accounts" method="get" result="y">
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="CB-ACCESS-KEY" value="#accessKey#" >
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="CB-ACCESS-SIGN" value="#ucase(cas)#" >
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="CB-ACCESS-TIMESTAMP" value="#timeStamp#" >
        <cfhttpparam type="header" name="CB-ACCESS-PASSPHRASE" value="#passPhrase#" >
    </cfhttp>
```

Comment: `CB-ACCESS-SIGN` is calculated incorrectly.  Hmac() returns hexadecimal, but ToBase64 can't encode hex strings properly, only plain strings (i.e. utf-8, ascii, etc..) or binary. Replace `toBase64( theHmac )` with `toBase64( binaryDecode(theHmac, "hex"))`.

Comment: Or better yet, use the decode/encode functions to convert from hex to base64  `binaryEncode( binaryDecode(theHmac, "hex"), "base64")`. The docs recommend those functions for new code instead of ToBase64

Comment: I'm sure it's some sort of encoding problem, but neither one of those changes worked, unfortunately. I still receive the "Invalid Signature" message.

Comment: I haven't used the api, but those things are definitely part of the problem. Also, the `timestamp` format looks off. The [examples I've seen](https://docs.pro.coinbase.com/#signing-a-message) all use a unix epoch, not a human readable date string, so you should try changing that as well.

Comment: ... and hmac() may also be mangling the key, again due to encoding.  This [CF snippet](https://trycf.com/gist/9b7164a5ed63fadd589cc4ecc5df5d5f/acf2016?theme=monokai) it produces the same `signature` as the [C# example](https://www.programmableweb.com/sample-source-code/coinbase-c-sample-code-iyalovoy) from the docs  - when using a hard coded timestamp `1623692403`. Ignore the different requestPath, it's just for testing

Comment: Oops, ignore the comment about the human friendly timestamp variable, didn't notice it wasn't being used. Anyway, try passing in a binary key to hmac to see if that makes a difference (either utf8 or base64 decoded) as it generates the same result as the example

Comment: In my code snippet above I was attempting to create an epoch time on my Windows machine. The API actually has a call you can make to get epoch, so I sorted that by just making a call to https://api.pro.coinbase.com/time to get that, and then I can resubmit that with the signature. Still working on the encoding. Thanks for your help SOS :)

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted. I have similar problem. Stuck on something.